# Invalid syntax on if and else statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, multiprocessing

I have a script that I'm trying read and write to a file after some calculations were made on the content of the file. I've set up an if-else block to monitor when to append the list and when to write to the file. The issue here is that I am getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the else block.

The indentation seems right to me but I have yet to see a posting on here that explains how to fix this particular issue.

```
with open(file_input, 'r') as fin:
    with open(file_output, 'a') as fout:
        writer.csv.writer(fout)
        cid_smiles_list  = []
        if len(cid_smiles_list) < 100:
            for rows in fin:
                split_list = rows.split(",")
                split_list.append(pqq)
                split_list.append(nac)
                cid_smiles_list.append(split_list)

        else len(cid_smiles_list) == 100:
            packaged_list = utils.mp_handler(cid_smiles_list, 
                            pool_size)
            writer.writerow(packaged_list)
            cid_smiles_list.clear()
```

Comment: else if, not else ;)

Comment: @hugo `elif` actually. But ya, you can't give `else` a condition.

Comment: @Carcigenicate right!

Comment: wow that was quite the detail i missed...thanks!

Comment: It's so obvious when you see but so easy to miss... I would almost say the interpreter should be like "you meant elif there, right?"

Comment: @RubenZapata Case solved, I think you can close this.

Comment: I posted the answer as community wiki because it was trivial and solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the `else:` block can't have a condition.

You meant to write:

```
if something:
  ...
elif something_else:
  ...
```

Comment: I just learnt about automatic deletion of question that don't provide much value, and I realize I prevented this question from getting removed by posting this answer (which I think it should)... what do you guys think?